# Re-write javascript function to avoid JQuery.json file not read by server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following javascript which I download from the [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/location-sensitive-map/?theme=frozen). The js inside HTML page, and the page not showing anything. I traced the code and found the issues from the line below:

```
jQuery.getJSON( "https://www.amcharts.com/tools/country/?v=xz6Z", function( geo ) {
```

running the URL returned json content `{"country_code":"YOUR-COUNTRY-CODE","country_name":"YOUR-COUNTRY-NAME"}`. This code trying to find your country code & name and showing the map based on your location. I'm not interested in this part because I always want the same country map regardless of the location.

So, as I a workaround, I changed the function with country code and name as variables to avoid using the query part. I'm not getting errors, However, nothing is showing.. Any suggestions?

Here is the full code with javascript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>map</title>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
    #chartdiv {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px
    }

    </style>

    <!-- Resources -->
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/data/countries2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Chart code -->
    <script>
    am4core.ready(function() {
    //import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
    // Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_material);
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end

    window.onload = function() {

    /**
     * This demo uses our own method of determining user's location
     * It is not public web service that you can use
     * You'll need to find your own. We recommend http://www.maxmind.com
     */
// I commented this line
//jQuery.getJSON( "https://www.amcharts.com/tools/country/?v=xz6Z", function( geo ) {
  function myFunction( ) {
       var country_code="KW";
       var country_name ="Kuwait";
      // Default map
      var defaultMap = "usaAlbersLow";

      // calculate which map to be used
      var currentMap = defaultMap;
      var title = "";
      if ( am4geodata_data_countries2[ country_code ] !== undefined ) {
        currentMap = am4geodata_data_countries2[ country_code ][ "maps" ][ 0 ];

        // add country title
        if ( am4geodata_data_countries2[ country_code ][ "country" ] ) {
          title = am4geodata_data_countries2[ country_code ][ "country" ];
        }

      }

      // Create map instance
      var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

      chart.titles.create().text = title;

      // Set map definition
      chart.geodataSource.url = "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/json/" + currentMap + ".json";
      chart.geodataSource.events.on("parseended", function(ev) {
        var data = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < ev.target.data.features.length; i++) {
          data.push({
            id: ev.target.data.features[i].id,
            value: Math.round( Math.random() * 10000 )
          })
        }
        polygonSeries.data = data;
      })

      // Set projection
      chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Mercator();

      // Create map polygon series
      var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

      //Set min/max fill color for each area
      polygonSeries.heatRules.push({
        property: "fill",
        target: polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template,
        min: chart.colors.getIndex(1).brighten(1),
        max: chart.colors.getIndex(1).brighten(-0.3)
      });

      // Make map load polygon data (state shapes and names) from GeoJSON
      polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

      // Set up heat legend
      let heatLegend = chart.createChild(am4maps.HeatLegend);
      heatLegend.series = polygonSeries;
      heatLegend.align = "right";
      heatLegend.width = am4core.percent(25);
      heatLegend.marginRight = am4core.percent(4);
      heatLegend.minValue = 0;
      heatLegend.maxValue = 40000000;
      heatLegend.valign = "bottom";

      // Set up custom heat map legend labels using axis ranges
      var minRange = heatLegend.valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
      minRange.value = heatLegend.minValue;
      minRange.label.text = "Little";
      var maxRange = heatLegend.valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
      maxRange.value = heatLegend.maxValue;
      maxRange.label.text = "A lot!";

      // Blank out internal heat legend value axis labels
      heatLegend.valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", function(labelText) {
        return "";
      });

      // Configure series tooltip
      var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
      polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}: {value}";
      polygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;
      polygonTemplate.strokeWidth = 0.5;

      // Create hover state and set alternative fill color
      var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
      hs.properties.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(1).brighten(-0.5);

    //});
    };

    };

    }); // end am4core.ready()
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery was using your function as a callback which was invoked after some json was fetched, but you took jquery out of the equation and so now nothing is calling your function.  at the bottom of your `<script>` tag, but still inside `window.onload = function() {`, add the following line:

`myFunction();`

to run it.